# Prove that there does not exist a homotopy for a space (similar to Topologist's Comb)

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

Suppose $X$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of straight-line segments joining $(0,1)$ to the points $(1/n,0)$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the segment joining $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$.
This space reminds me of the Topologist's comb, but is not exactly it.

(1) Prove that $X$ is contractible. (This one I think I know how to do, basically the straight line homotopy $F((x,y),t)=(1-t)(x,y)+t(0,1)$)

(2) Prove that there does not exist a homotopy $F:X\times I\to X$ such that $F(x,0)=x$, $F(x,1)=f(x)$, and $F((0,0),t)=(0,0)$ for $x\in X$ and $0\leq t\leq 1$. [Edit: $f(x):=(0,0)$ for all $x\in X$.]

I think (2) means in words that we can't have a homotopy that fixes the origin, and at $t=1$ all points end up at the origin.

My thoughts on (2): Basically I think the approach is suppose that $F$ exists, and contradict the continuity of $F$, but I am not sure how to put it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is $f(x)$??

Comment: @Anubhav.K Oh yes, I missed that out. $f(x)=(0,0)$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: observe that if such $F$ exists then  for any fixed $t$ due to continuity $F((1/n,0),t) \tendsto (0,0) $ , now try to find the contradiction by using continuity argument

Comment: @Anubhav.K Thanks, I am stuck at exactly this step! What $t$ should I choose?

Comment: ok, now for each $(1/n,0)$ point you'll get a let say $t_n$ s.t $F((1/n,0),t_n) = (0,1)$ , since $[0,1]$ is compact so will will get a convergent sequence of {$t_n$} , which will converge to $t_0$, now try to argue that point will be a bad point